# Joomla Component into Module

Tags: component, module, database, update

I just want to call a specific function in a component.

From the RokGallery Component in:

> com_rokgallery\lib\RokGallery\Model\file.php

there is a function called `&createNew` that I need in a module.

Does anyone know how I can call this from my module and give them specific variables?

It's already being called in the following file on line 31:

> components\com_rokgallery\lib\RokGallery\Job\Processor\import.php

I hope someone can help me ....

Comment: Have you tried importing the rokgallery library, then using `RokGallery_Model_Slice::createNew($foo, $foo, $foo, $foo);` ?

Comment: I´m new in developing modules... How can I do this ? Did I need to do this in the module.php/.xml or helper.php ? And how can i call it.. Sorry for that tho..

Comment: @Lodder forgot to link u

Comment: I would suggest in the helper.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try using a plugin called [Components Anywhere](http://extensions.joomla.org/profile/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/components-anywhere) by NoNumber. You can use it to load a component inside any module (or article) by adding

```
 {component url/of/the/component}
```

anywhere you want the component to be loaded.

Comment: Okey thanks! 
So I´ve my helper.php and a function called update(), how can I do this?